# Converter um link de texto em um link href

Tags: php, regex

Tenho um site onde tenho um editor(html) só q as vezes ao invés de usarem o botão para postar o link as pessoas colam o link e ele fica em texto então estou uma expressão regular para converter o texto em link

```
$reply = preg_replace(
    "/(?<![\>https?:\/\/|href=\"'])(?<http>(https?:[\/][\/]|www\.)([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|[\/.&?= ]|[~])*)/",
    "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>",
    $reply
);
```

Ocorre que se o link tiver "-"

http://www.webmotors.com.br/comprar/audi/a6/3-0-limousine-v6-30v-gasolina-4p-multitronic/4-portas/2002/13395497

esse link não funciona, ele corta no "-"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para isso basta adicionar o *hífen* e o *underscore* na lista de captura.

```
(?<![\>https?:\/\/|href=\"'])(?<http>(https?:[\/][\/]|www\.)([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|[\/.&?=\-_ ]|[~])*)
                                                                                       ^^
```

Seu código ficara semelhante a isto:

```
$reply = preg_replace(
"/(?<![\>https?:\/\/|href=\"'])(?<http>(https?:[\/][\/]|www\.)([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|[\/.&?=\-_ ]|[~])*)/",
"<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>",
$reply);
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://code.viper-7.com/p57ohJ)</kbd>

Comment: Mas a solução não funciona com esse link http://cs624822.vk.me/v624822852/24ca1/KJepZpJimf0.jpg
ou esse
http://imworld.aufeminin.com/story/20150108/caique-laura-e-marocs-570188_w1000.jpg

Comment: @DanielLemes No primeiro *link* funciona sim, no segundo não funcionava porque continha um underline `_`, já atualizei a resposta e coloquei isso também.

Answer (score 0):

Uma sugestão é simplificar e juntar o `-` na regex.

```
/(?<![\>https?:\/\/|href=\"'])(?<http>(https?:[\/][\/]|www\.)([a-zA-Z0-9\/.&?=-~-]+)*)/
```

#### Exemplo: https://regex101.com/r/pN8lY1/1

a parte que mudei foi para `[a-zA-Z0-9\/.&?=-~-]+`, retirei os `|` e juntei `-` nas possibilidades de caracteres. Removí o espaço em branco, que um URL não deve ter.

Comment: Este código não insere o http:// se eu digitar no texto www.abc.com.br vai converter em link como <a href="www.abc.com.br">www.p3h8.com.br</a> ausente o http:// o link não funciona.