# Converter links de texto em link html

Tags: php, regex

Eu vi a solução daqui [Converter um link de texto em um link href](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53404/converter-um-link-de-texto-em-um-link-href) e várias outras e acabei por adaptar para minha necessidade, mas existem alguns problemas.

Eu preciso converter os links e os links de imagem em imagem e hiperlink estou fazendo o seguinte.

```
$reply = preg_replace(
            "/(?<![\>https?:\/\/|href=\"'])(?<http>(https?:[\/][\/]|www\.)([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|[\/.;&?=#_\-\+\ ]|[~])*)/",
            "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>",
            $reply
        );

        $reply = preg_replace('~<a[^>]*?href="(.*?(gif|jpeg|jpg|png|GIF|JPEG|JPG))".*?</a>~', '<img src="$1" />', $reply);

        $reply = preg_replace("/<a(.*?)>/", "<a$1 target=\"_blank\">", $reply);
```

exemplo:

```
&lt;center&gt; &lt;a href=&quot;http://www.yoble.com.br/Community/434&quot;&gt; &lt;img src=&quot;https://lh4.ggpht.com/-05_v3FOUAlc/VHPHsM_MObI/AAAAAAAABeQ/4FodgebUMe0/s00/FDS043.png&quot;&gt;
```

o código acima é para ser visualizado como código então aquele endereço não deveria ser convertido.

bom nota-se que eu pego qualquer link e converto para um href, depois eu verifico se é imagem e troco o `<a>` por `<img>` e por último acrescento aos links a `target`.
Os problemas, links que contém "," não funcionam, quando o usuário usa um link formatado com uma imagem no meio ele tenta fazer essa conversão, eu gostaria de ignorar esses links prontos e apenas adicionar a `target=\"_blank\">"`

Obrigado.

Comment: A tua solução tem alguns problemas: (1) quando o url está no fim da linha; (2) www.... gera links inválidos; (3) gera duplos target=...;

Comment: Podes dar exemplos de strings que tens na origem e como queres que apareçam depois?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para lidar com edição de HTML, expressões regulares não são a melhor hitótese:
é mais adecuado soluções baseadas em **parsers de html/xml**.

Mantendo no entanto a abordagem da pergunta inicial:

```
$reply = preg_replace('~(?<![\'"])(https?://\S+(gif|jpe?g|png))~i',  ## jpeg  -> img
                      "<img src='$1'>", $reply);

$reply = preg_replace('~(?<![\'"])(https?://\S+)~',                  ## http  -> a href
                      "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>", $reply);

$reply = preg_replace('~(?<![\'"/])(www.\w\S+)~',                    ## www.x -> a href
                      "<a href='http://$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>", $reply);
```

**EDIT 1**: (removi por estar contido na ediçao 2)

**EDIT2**:
A substituição de `URL` por `<f href='URL'>URL</a>`, só ocorre se URL não
estiver a seguir `'` ou `"`.

Para lidar com a situações de links previamente anotatos e outras situações a não anotar,
acrecentei:

1. uma marca `''PrOtEcT''` antes do endereço (como encosta uma `'` ao endereço, este
   não será anotado)
2. no final retiramos a marca

ou seja:

```
$contexto_esq = '   <a\s.*?>\s*           # proteger após <a...>
                  | &quot;                # proteger após &quot,
                ';

$txt= preg_replace("~($contexto_esq)( https? | www. )~ix",        # add ''PrOtEcT''
                      "$1''PrOtEcT''$2", $txt);

$txt= preg_replace('~(?<![\'"])(https?://\S+(gif|jpe?g|png))~i',  # jpeg -> img
                      "<img src='$1'>", $txt);

$txt= preg_replace('~(?<![\'"])(https?://\S+)~',                  # http -> a href
                      "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>", $txt);

$txt= preg_replace('~(?<![\'"/])(www.\w\S+)~',                    # www. -> a hreg
                      "<a href='http://$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>", $txt);

$txt= preg_replace("~''PrOtEcT''~","",$txt);                      # remove ''PrOtEcT''
```

**Política de testes** Como as condições do exercício não estão definidas e estão sempre a mudar, 
é crucial  usar  um conjunto de exemplos de teste (que idealmente deviam 
estar no enunciado)

```
$txt =  <<<EOD
1) anotar com <a>:
http://n.u.pt/  mais  www.di.br e http://www.di.br 
2) não anotar:
"http://n.u.pt/sss1"  e 'www.di.br' e 'http://www.di.br' 
3) anotar com <img>:
http://n.u.pt/sss2.jpg  e ainda http://www.di.br/dir/f.png
4) não anotar:
"http://n.u.pt/sss3.jpg"  e ainda 'http://www.di.br/dir/f.png'
5) já anotado:
<a href="http://n.u.pt/" target="_blank">http://n.u.pt/</a>
6) já anotadao
<a href="http://n.u.pt/" target="_blank">   http://n.u.pt/f.jpg</a>
7) não anotar:
href=&quot;http://www.yoble.com.br/Community/434&quot;&gt; &lt;img 

EOD;
```

No caso presente está a produzir:

```
1) anotar com <a>:
<a href='http://n.u.pt/' target='_blank'>http://n.u.pt/</a>  mais  <a href='http://www.di.br' target='_blank'>www.di.br</a> e <a href='http://www.di.br' target='_blank'>http://www.di.br</a>
2) não anotar:
"http://n.u.pt/sss1"  e 'www.di.br' e 'http://www.di.br'
3) anotar com <img>:
<img src='http://n.u.pt/sss2.jpg'>  e ainda <img src='http://www.di.br/dir/f.png'>
4) não anotar:
"http://n.u.pt/sss3.jpg"  e ainda 'http://www.di.br/dir/f.png'
5) já anotado:
<a href="http://n.u.pt/" target="_blank">http://n.u.pt/</a>
6) já anotadao
<a href="http://n.u.pt/" target="_blank">   http://n.u.pt/f.jpg</a>
7) não anotar:
href=&quot;http://www.yoble.com.br/Community/434&quot;&gt; &lt;img
```

Comment: Isso tem um problema, como eu uso um editor o usuário pode digitar algo como 
<a href="http://i.imgur.com/5EpFaEd.jpg">http://i.imgur.com/5EpFaEd.jpg</a>

E a tua expressão iria pegar esse caso e quero que ela ignore casos onde o endereço esteja já formatado

Comment: Daniel, juntei uma nova versão para colmatar a seituação que referes. Se fores encontrando mais casos, ajudava se criasses um exemplo concreto com os vários casos que não estejam ainda cobertos.

Comment: edite o post, veja lá um outro exemplo que não funciona.

Comment: Ver revisão (Edit 2).